# How to return dynamically allocated array from function and correctly delete it

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm new to C++ and I have a problem with memory management.

I have one function `a()` that calls 3 functions (`b()`, `c()`, `d()`), each one of which returns a dynamically allocated array of `MyClass` objects:

```
void a(){
    MyClass * one=b();
    MyClass * two=c();
    MyClass * three=d();
    //operate with 3 array (one, two and three)
    delete [] one;
    delete [] two;
    delete [] three;
}

MyClass * b(){
    MyClass * array=new MyClass[2000];
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}

MyClass * c(){
    MyClass * array=new MyClass[2000];
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}

MyClass * d(){
    MyClass * array=new MyClass[2000];
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}
```

After many operations in `a()` I must delete the 3 arrays that I created with the 3 functions. If I do it using the 3 `delete []` expressions like those in the code above, is it ok?

I asked myself this question because I think that this code deallocates everything correctly, but analyzing the memory allocation of my c++ program I see no evidence of this deletion.

Comment: No it is not ok. If you create with `new[]` you should use `delete[]`

Comment: @KillzoneKid Yes, you are right but I forgot to write it in my question, but in the code I correctly do with delete[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing is correct.

However, note that manual memory management is prone to bugs, be it memory leaks or double deletion. It's *much* better to forget about naked `new` and especially `delete`, and instead use RAII classes for handling this safely.

In your case, you should replace the pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays with `std::vector`. `std::vector` is *the* way to spell "dynamically allocated array" in C++. Once you do that, you will know that the vector will take care of deallocating the memory correctly, even in the presence of exceptions.

This is what your code could look like with `std::vector`:

```
void a(){
    auto one=b();
    auto two=c();
    auto three=d();
    //operate with 3 array (one, two and three)

    //nothing to do here, the vectors will deallocate memory correctly when they go out of scope
}

std::vector<MyClass> b(){
    std::vector<MyClass> array(2000);
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}

std::vector<MyClass> c(){
    std::vector<MyClass> array(2000);
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}

std::vector<MyClass> d(){
    std::vector<MyClass> array(2000);
    //many operations on array
    return array;
}
```

---

As for why you can't see effects of the deallocation: memory freed by `delete` need not be immediately returned to the operating system. Quite often, the C++ runtime will keep hold of it and use it to satisfy future allocation requirements of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Probably I can't see the effect of the deallocation for the reason that you explain.

Comment: PS. for "dynamically allocated array" I didn't mean the possibility to grow 
 (make smaller) dynamically the array but I mean the allocation on heap memory to use pointer to this data structure.
So to do the combo: Heap memory+array that can resize dynamically I must use a syntax like this:
std::vector * myArray=new std::vector(2000);
Is it true?

Comment: @Antonio1996 No, of course not. Just do `std::vector<MyClass> myArray(2000);`. The vector's *data* is always allocated dynamically, and that's what I mean in the answer too.

Comment: Ahh ok, so if I create std::vector<MyClass> myArray(2000); , when myArray go out of scope, automatically will be called destructor of vector and destructor for all of my MyClass objects? But with this situation when myArray go out of scope I lose all. If I want the freedom to decide when delete it I can use a pointer of std::vector<MyClass>? I'm confused :(

Comment: @Antonio1996 You might want to pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to get a firmer grip on the internal working. In this particular case, you will not "lose all" since you will return the vector from the function. I will edit the answer to show what the code would look like with `std::vector`.

Comment: ok, I understand your example, many thanks. Last question: can you give me an example when is more convenient use a pointer of vector rather than a vector?

Comment: @Antonio1996 Not really; using a `std::vector<T>*` is *extremely* rare. Allocating the vector itself dynamically (that is, `new std::vector<T>`) is even rarer. Normal C++ code simply does not need constructs like that.

Answer (score 5):

For reliable memory-management you should use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`. So when your function is returning a dynamically allocated value it should instead return `std::unique_ptr` to that value to make sure that this value will be deallocated.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> array(new MyClass[2000]);
```

In your case however you should consider using `std::vector` instead of raw array.